# Using Reg Ex in jQuery selection

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm looking for a convenient way to use jQuery to remove all classes from an object that match a particular format. This seems like a natural fit for Reg Ex, but I can't seem to find any documentation on jQuery supporting them in selectors. I figured StackOverflow would provide a quicker solution.

Given the HTML below, what is the most convenient means of removing any class that begins with "child_"?

I don't need the solution to involve Reg Ex, it's just what seems natural given the problem. Any clean jQuery solution will work.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="child_1 child_12">Item 1</li>
  <li class="child_4 child_6">Item 2</li>
  <li class="child_3 child_1 stays_put">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:
I should clarify that the purpose is to remove the *class*, not the element. When the code is done, all the list elements should still be there, but with the *classes* removed. When completed, it should look like this.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="">Item 1</li>
  <li class=">Item 2</li>
  <li class="stays_put">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: my bad on not asking the proper question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. It finds every element with the `child_` in the class name, and then removes only those classes with `child_`

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/CZ5yg/7/)***

```
var partial = /^child_/g;
$('[class*=child_]').each(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');

    for(var i=0; i< classes.length;i++){
        if(classes[i].match(partial)){ 
            $(this).removeClass(classes[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work if the `class` attribute looks like this: `<li class="foo child_2" >...</li>`.

Comment: Use Firebug or WebKit dev tools to inspect your source. It's not actually removing the child class from that last element. The background is blue because the two CSS selectors you're using have equal specificity, but the `.test { background-color: blue; }` rule comes later in the stylesheet. Switch the rules, and you'll see: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/GVYCT/1/

Comment: @Matt Ball Yeah your right, I changed ^ to * and it works because itll now find any occurance of child_ regardless of where it is at. It will still however only remove the ones that start with child_, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Okay, that's good enough for me (+1). One other suggestion: use a regex literal (also, write a faster regex): `/^child_/g`, and create the regex outside of the scope of the callback to `each`. These are micro-optimizations at this point, but good ideas nonetheless.

Comment: just one more minor note `var i = classes.length; while (i--) {}` will be faster than the "for" loop - basis for my comment: http://blogs.sun.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a