# Remove all class from an element matching a specific format, using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I asked a similar question earlier, however my wording provided correctly submitted answers but not for the question I was actually trying to answer:) In an attempt to not muddle SO's listings, I've posted this question separately.

Given the HTML below, what is the most convenient means of removing all the *classes* from #item_3 that begins with "child_"?

The solution needs to be able to keep the "stays_put" class and not effect any of the other list elements.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li id="item_1" class="child_1 child_12">Item 1</li>
  <li id="item_2" class="child_4 child_6">Item 2</li>
  <li id="item_3" class="child_3 child_1 stays_put">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

The question that I originally asked, can be found here.
[Using Reg Ex in jQuery selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317058/using-reg-ex-in-jquery-selection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I suppose you could mess with the `class` attribute directly, like this:

```
$('#item_3').attr('class', function() {
    return $.trim($(this).attr('class').replace(/child_\S+/g, ''));
});
```

Basically you search for classes prefixed with `child_`, replace with nothing, then set the `class` attribute with the resulting string. The regex `/child_\S+/g` matches `child_` followed by non-whitespace character(s), since class names are space-separated.

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/HKFyH/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of `split` and [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
var classes = $('#item_3').attr('class').split(' ');
$.each( classes, function( idx, val ) {
   if( val.indexOf('child_') === 0 ) {
      $('#item_3').removeClass( val );
   }
});
```